# what is the relation between GIMP and GTK+?

Tags: graphic

I was wondering what is the relation between GIMP and GTK+. I read that GTK+ is GIMP Tool Kit, but is GIMP included in GTK+?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If I am not mistaken, GTK was the GUI toolkit that was initially developed for GIMP. It was then adopted by the GNOME project as its primary toolkit

Answer (score 0):

The GIMP is an application that uses GTK+ as its toolkit.

The GIMP was 1st released as an application without separating toolkit. Then the toolkit has been separated from application, and called GTK.